# wrong result from cfmodule with firefox

Tags: coldfusion, fckeditor

In coldfusion 8, I used bellow code to view "UserDesc"field data from database table that is working on well IE and chrome but not on Firefox. On firefox it does not display on fckeditor,but shows on textarea. please suggest any change in code.

```
<cfmodule
                template="fckeditor/fckeditor.cfm"
                basePath="../views/fckeditor/"
                instanceName="Question"
                value='#UrlDecode(UserDesc)#'
                width="530"
                height="260">
```

Comment: What have you expected? What are you getting? What have you tried? What is the value of `UserDesc`?

Comment: "Not performing well" is too vague a description. You need to [be more specific](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). In order to help, we need to know 1) exactly what results you *are* getting 2) how they differ from you *expected* and 3) the input that caused these results. Without more specific information, all anyone can do is guess ..

Answer (score 1):

There are a few newer ways to use the ckeditor in Coldfusion. You can just use the following (this may be cf9+ only, i'm not sure):

```
    <cftextarea name="Question" id="Question" 
        richtext="yes" 
        value="#UrlDecode(UserDesc)#">
    </cftextarea>
```

Or you could just use the javascript one as demo'd here (this should work for any version of coldfusion): http://ckeditor.com/demo You would just have to put your value in between the opening and closing text area tags.

Comment: Try the javascript one, it's much nicer than the old one anyway.

Comment: Technically they are *all* javascript ;-) CF9 just provides a wrapper that simplifies the integration.